# Problem with div element not position side by side

Tags: html, css

I have a code in blade.php that need to show images. Ideally, the images should stack side by side with div element. But it seems not working.

I tried `flex`, `bootstrap` and `float`. Use `display` in html element.

```css
.lightbox img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  max-height: 198px;
  display: flex;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"> @foreach($post as $post)
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <a class="lightbox" href="/storage/{{ $post}}">
      <img src="/storage/{{ $post }}" class="w-25">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

[Here is current view-it show up and down images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bE2Y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing position of your `@foreach` may help:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      @foreach($post as $post)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <a class="lightbox" href="/storage/{{ $post}}">
                <img src="/storage/{{ $post }}" class="w-25">
            </a>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
```

Comment: it works. Thank you. Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: Because if you put your `@foreach` outside the `row`, it will create multiple row in the html.

Comment: oh ok, means that I keep nesting new row inside previous row right? Thank you sir

Comment: No. you created multiple separated row and each row has one image.